# Reading values out of an input box html

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Your Page</h1>
    <p id="Paragraph"></p>
    <form style="display: block;"><label for="Name" id="name" class="">Name: <input type="text" required></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label for="Category" id="category">Category: <input type="text" required ></label></form>
    <button type="button" id="New_Field" style="font-family: Whitney,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; height: 50px ;background-color: rgb(24, 255, 24); width: 100px; color: black;">New Page</button>
    <button type="button" id="Generate">Generate</button>
    <form style="display: block;"><label for="FIELD_1" id="FIELD_1"><input type="text"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label for="VALUE_1" id="VALUE_1"><input type="text"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label for="FIELD_2" id="FIELD_2"><input type="text"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label for="VALUE_2" id="VALUE_2"><input type="text"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label for="FIELD_3" id="FIELD_3"><input type="text"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label for="VALUE_3" id="VALUE_3"><input type="text"></label></form>
    <p id="code">Code: </p>
    <script>
        var FIELD = 1;
        var VALUE = 1;
        var MAX = 3;
        for(FIELD && VALUE;FIELD<MAX && VALUE<MAX;FIELD++ && VALUE++){
            const FI=document.getElementById('FIELD_'+FIELD);
            const VL=document.getElementById('VALUE_'+FIELD);
            FI.style.display="none";
            VL.style.display="none";
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var FIELD = 1;
        var VALUE = 1;
        var string = "!Auth ";
        const btn = document.getElementById('New_Field');
        //const newparagraph = document.getElementById('Paragraph');
        const code = document.getElementById('code');
        const generate = document.getElementById('Generate');
        
        btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var FIELD_ = document.getElementById('FIELD_'+FIELD);
            var VALUE_ = document.getElementById('VALUE_'+VALUE);
            FIELD++;
            VALUE++;
            //newparagraph.textContent="--Generate the stuff under here--";
            //FIELD_1.style.display="none";
            //FIELD_.style.display="none";
            if(FIELD_.style.display=="none"){
                FIELD_.style.display="block";
            }
            if(VALUE_.style.display=="none"){
                VALUE_.style.display="block";
            }
            //document.body.innerHTML(alert("FIELD :"+FIELD+"\nVALUE: "+VALUE));
            /*else{
                FIELD_1.style.display="none"
            }
            */
        })
        const Name=document.getElementById('name');
        const Category=document.getElementById('category');
        //Name.addEventListener("play",)
        
        generate.addEventListener("click", function() {
        
            string = "!Auth "+Category.value+" "+Name.value+" "
            for(var fi=1;fi<FIELD;fi++){
                var RDFI = document.getElementById("FIELD_"+fi);
                var RDVL = document.getElementById("VALUE_"+fi);
                var acvaFI=RDFI.value;
                var acvaVL=RDVL.value;
                string=string+"#"+acvaFI+" "+acvaVL+"\n";
                
            }
            code.textContent="Code: \n"+string
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make a website that will generate you a home page as i have a working Workshop but the command may be a little confusing. Thats why i made this so that ppl can visualise what their home page might look like. But i ran into an issue... I can not seem to be able to read the values out of the input box. Here is what i was intending to make
|NAME: |
|CATEGORY: |
|FIELD|
|VALUE|
...
because my command is >!Auth   <Each field starts with a # and its name can be only one word and their can be a maximum up to 20 fields but for the website for now there are only 3 FIELDS and 3 VALUES>.

Comment: Are you receiving an error?

Comment: you can have multiple `<input>` elements inside one `<form>`, have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Comment: @Ari Seyhun Im not recieving an error but when you hit generate it counts it as undefined

Comment: @caramba yes and thanks i guess?

Comment: and you don't have that. Is that for a reason? Not having that makes things more complicated in the long run.

Comment: I still don't understand why it is giving me an underfined when it clearly is declared by its value? By clearly i mean i *think* it should work

Comment: @caramba i know i am just really early into html so thats the way i made that :| sorry to bother any programmer or page creator who actually knows what he is doing its just that i don't XD

Comment: You're trying to get `.value` of a html `label` element, rather than the input itself for `name` and `Category`

Comment: no worries, I'm also just trying to help you here and that's the first thing I saw. Anyways. your problem is your selector: `document.getElementById('category')` which is a label and a `label` has no `value` you want to get the input element from the category. But you have multiple questions and problems in one that's why I will not try to answer your question as there are too many.

Comment: so intead of getting it from the label i should get it from the input so have something like so? 
```<form style="display: block;"><label for="Category">Category: <input type="text" required id="category"></label></form>```

Comment: You don't need to use `for` if the label is wrapped around the input.

Comment: But if you do use `for` you write it all lowercase so it can match the `id` from the input. Otherwise the click on the label will not focus the input. even the input is wrapped by the label. (see/try/click here: https://jsfiddle.net/uh2dv3ec/)

Comment: @caramba I fixed it and it should now work :D ill edit the question with the fixed code! Tysm btw!

I did mess up with how i hide stuff so i did have to move The 3rd one to be in first place and the first one replacing it

Comment: @DcraftBg: don’t put the “fixed code” in the question. If you’ve solved your problem post the answer as an *answer*. And, of course, explain that answer so that others can learn from your experience without having to read the comments (which are transitory, and often deleted).

Comment: @DavidThomas ty ill do that right now!

Answer (score 1):

By doing this `const Name=document.getElementById('name');` you are getting the `<label>` element, not the `<input>` element, that's why `Name.value` is `undefined`.

The value of the `for` attribute must be a single ID for a form related element in the same document as the  element.

You should add `id` attribute to `<input>` element:

```
<form style="display: block;">
  <label for="Name" id="name" class="">Name: 
    <input id="Name" type="text" required>
  </label>
</form>
```

then change this:

```
const Name=document.getElementById('name');
```

to this:

```
const Name=document.getElementById('Name');
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the "fixed" code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Your Page</h1>
    <p id="Paragraph"></p>
    <form style="display: block;"><label>Name: <input type="text" required id="name"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label>Category: <input type="text" required id="category"></label></form>
    <button type="button" id="New_Field" style="font-family: Whitney,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; height: 50px ;background-color: rgb(24, 255, 24); width: 100px; color: black;">New Page</button>
    <button type="button" id="Generate">Generate</button>
    <form style="display: block;"><label><input type="text" id="FIELD_3" style="width: 300px;"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label><input type="text" id="VALUE_3" style="height: 75px;width: 300px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; columns: 4;"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label><input type="text" id="FIELD_2" style="width: 300px;"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label><input type="text" id="VALUE_2" style="height: 75px;width: 300px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; columns: 4;"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label><input type="text" id="FIELD_1" style="width: 300px;"></label></form>
    <form style="display: block;"><label><input type="text" id="VALUE_1" style="height: 75px;width: 300px; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; columns: 4;"></label></form>
    <pre id="code">Code: </pre>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("name").value="TEST";
        document.getElementById("category").value="Maps";
        var FIELD = 1;
        var VALUE = 1;
        var MAX = 3;
        for(FIELD && VALUE;FIELD<MAX && VALUE<MAX;FIELD++ && VALUE++){
            const FI=document.getElementById('FIELD_'+FIELD);
            const VL=document.getElementById('VALUE_'+FIELD);
            FI.style.display="none";
            VL.style.display="none";
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        var FIELD = 1;
        var VALUE = 1;
        var string = "!Auth ";
        const btn = document.getElementById('New_Field');
        //const newparagraph = document.getElementById('Paragraph');
        const code = document.getElementById('code');
        const generate = document.getElementById('Generate');
        
        btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
            var FIELD_ = document.getElementById('FIELD_'+FIELD);
            var VALUE_ = document.getElementById('VALUE_'+VALUE);
            FIELD++;
            VALUE++;
            //alert("FIELD_"+FIELD+"\nVALUE_"+VALUE);
            //newparagraph.textContent="--Generate the stuff under here--";
            //FIELD_1.style.display="none";
            //FIELD_.style.display="none";
            if(FIELD_.style.display=="none"){
                FIELD_.style.display="block";
            }
            if(VALUE_.style.display=="none"){
                VALUE_.style.display="block";
            }
            //document.body.innerHTML(alert("FIELD :"+FIELD+"\nVALUE: "+VALUE));
            /*else{
                FIELD_1.style.display="none"
            }
            */
        })
        const Name=document.getElementById('name');
        const Category=document.getElementById('category');
        //Name.addEventListener("play",)
        
        generate.addEventListener("click", function() {
            string = "!Auth "+Category.value+" "+Name.value+" "
            string = string+"#"+document.getElementById("FIELD_3").value+" "+document.getElementById("VALUE_3").value+"\n";
            //alert(string = string+"#"+document.getElementById("FIELD_3").value+" "+document.getElementById("VALUE_3").value+"\n");
            for(var fi=1;fi<FIELD;fi++){
                var RDFI = document.getElementById("FIELD_"+(fi));
                //alert("Reading:\nFIELD_"+fi);
                var RDVL = document.getElementById("VALUE_"+(fi));
                //alert("Reading:\nVALUE_"+fi);
                var acvaFI=RDFI.value;
                var acvaVL=RDVL.value;
                
                string=string+"#"+acvaFI+" "+acvaVL+"\n";
            }
            string = string;
            code.textContent="Code: "+string;
            //document.body.innerHTML("<pre>")+string+document.body.innerHTML("<\pre>")

        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```